# Introduction books and background for group testing

Tags: references, pooling

I went to a colloquium about group testing and found it to be extremely interesting. I would like to learn more about it. Any recommendations on introductory theoretical books about group testing? What is the recommended background before beginning to study this topic? Thanks

(I am a first-year graduate student in Statistics)